# Wordpress taxonomy & term templates (404)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I want to add a section with photos on my website. Photos should be grouped with the help of taxonomies and custom_post_types. Links should be something like this

- `mysite.com/photography` => taxonomy template
- `mysite.com/photography/underwater` => taxonomy term template

I created taxonomy and custom_post_type in my `functions.php`, here is code.

```
function photos_custom_post_type() {
$labels = array(
    'name'                => __( 'Photos' ),
    'singular_name'       => __( 'Photo'),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Photos'),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Photo'),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Photos'),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Photo'),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Photo'),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New'),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Photo'),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Photo'),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Photo'),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found'),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash')
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'photos'),
    'description'         => __( 'Best Photos'),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title','thumbnail',),
    'public'              => true,
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
);
    register_post_type( 'photos', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'photos_custom_post_type', 0 );

// creating Taxonomy for Custom Post Type
add_action( 'init', 'photos_custom_taxonomy', 0 );
function photos_custom_taxonomy() {

$labels = array(
'name' => _x( 'Photos Category', 'taxonomy general name' ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'Photos Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Photos Category' ),
'all_items' => __( 'All Photos Category' ),
'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Photos Category' ),
'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Photos Category:' ),
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Photos Category' ), 
'update_item' => __( 'Update Photos Category' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Photos Category' ),
'new_item_name' => __( 'New Photos Category Name' ),
'menu_name' => __( 'Photos Category' ),
);  

register_taxonomy('photos_cat',array('photos'), array(
'hierarchical' => true,
'labels' => $labels,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_admin_column' => true,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'photography', 'with_front' => false)
));
}
```

I also created

- `taxonomy-post_cat-underwater.php` => this works
- `taxonomy-post_cat.php` => this doesn't

When I go to `mysite.com/photography/underwater` => everything is working, but when I go to `mysite.com/photography` => I get 404 error..

Help me please to understand what's going wrong.

Comment: set WP_DEBUG = true in wp-config.php . what is the error messege?

Comment: @elicohenator No errors, just 404 page

Answer (score 0):

you have to follow the Taxonomy Template rules as noted in WP developers docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/#custom-taxonomy

> The hierarchy for a custom taxonomy is listed below:

1. taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php: For example, if the taxonomy is named “sometax,” and the taxonomy’s term is “someterm,” WordPress would look for a file named taxonomy-sometax-someterm.php.
2. taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php: For example, if the taxonomy is named “sometax,” WordPress would look for a file named taxonomy-sometax.php
3. taxonomy.php
4. archive.php
5. index.php

Comment: I know that. And I already created `taxonomy-post_cat-underwater.php` and ''taxonomy-post_cat.php . First is working, second not.

Comment: That's because the higher hirarchy file overrides the second file. Change the files name and you'll see its working.